# Getting lag when making rolling predictions with ARIMA (pmd auto_arima)

Tags: python, arima

I am creating a trading bot using prediction models (university porpuses), in this case I am using an ARIMA model.
The problem is that when I make the predictions I get a lag, the predicted data is one step behind the real data.
I have already tested if the train/test data was wrong, but everythings seems ok.

I have this code (preditcion function):

```
self.model = auto_arima(self.history, seasonal=False, suppress_warnings=True, stepwise=True)
        for i in range(len(self.test)):
            self.model = self.model.fit(self.history)
            yhat = self.model.predict(n_periods=1)[0]
            self.model_predictions.append(yhat)
            true_test_value = self.test.iloc[i]['Adj Close']
            self.history.append(true_test_value)
            print('predicted=%f, expected=%f' % (yhat, true_test_value))
        mse = mean_squared_error(self.test['Adj Close'], self.model_predictions)
        rmse = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(self.test['Adj Close'], self.model_predictions))
        print(f"MSE: {mse:.2f}")
        print(f"RMSE: {rmse:.2f}")
```

Example of the lag
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NywTB.png)

First results:

```
predicted=1836.317442, expected=1835.900024
predicted=1834.238775, expected=1822.599976
predicted=1820.928936, expected=1823.800049
predicted=1821.459139, expected=1837.900024
predicted=1836.037658, expected=1867.500000
predicted=1866.423275, expected=1867.800049
predicted=1869.151247, expected=1881.300049
predicted=1881.677788, expected=1881.800049
predicted=1882.165495, expected=1876.699951
predicted=1876.317468, expected=1884.599976
```

As you can see the predictions are one step behind.

I have tried this:

self.model = self.model.fit(self.history[:-1])

But did not work.